# Data migration and storeURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, data-migration

I have app on app store and I set up storeURL to : Model 2.sqlite. It working good but now maybe 2 months later, I am working on new version app, I added new model version and set storeURL: Model.sqlite. But I cant migrate from old version(lightweight migration). When I set storeURL to : Model 2.sqlite and start my app, console show me `Can't find model for source store`. Where can be the problem? I dont wanna lose data from old version.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The store URL is where your persistent store is put. It is logically nothing to do with the format of that store. Most apps will change their model several times but never once change the store's URL.

Your error suggests you've either removed the old version of your model from the build or, for some reason, declined to use a versioned model at all. If you were to open your current Xcode project now, would the old version of your model be in it? Is it located such that Core Data could be expected to know its relationship to the new?

Comment: I dont know what do you mean. Can I restore Model 2.sqlite? I have old version where can I find it?

Comment: A SQLite file is a store. A model is something completely different.